# not found (Errcode: 22 "Invalid argument")

Tags: java, sql, csv, file-upload

I am trying to load data from .csv file by

```
try (Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()) {
            String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" + path.toAbsolutePath()
                    + "' INTO TABLE persons FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
                    + " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (PersonID, FirstName, City) ";
            System.out.println(loadQuery);
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(loadQuery);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but I am getting the following error

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\temp\fileupload.csv' INTO TABLE persons FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '
' (PersonID, FirstName, City) 
java.sql.SQLException: File 'D:\    empfileupload.csv' not found (Errcode: 22 "Invalid argument")
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1072)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3563)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3495)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2687)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2616)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:782)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:625)
    at com.coin.pay.controller.IndexController.readCsvUsingLoad(IndexController.java:203)
    at com.coin.pay.controller.IndexController.uploadCSVtoDB(IndexController.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at      org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
```

org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

How should I solve this? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't this *"`D:\    emp`"* that the `\t` in the path has been interpreted as a tab? Isn't it obvious to at least test to escape it? Like `\\t`?

Comment: You have to cast the "\" in your string with "\": `...INFILE 'D:\\temp...`. "\t" is a tabulator-sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should escape the backslash in `\n` inside your `LOAD DATA` statement to tell Java that it is a literal `\n` and not a real line break:

```
String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" + path.toAbsolutePath()
                + "' INTO TABLE persons FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
                + " LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' (PersonID, FirstName, City) ";
```

As others have said, you should also escape the path to your file.